# How to enhance CompletableFuture Join Performance

Tags: java, spring, completable-future

im working in java project where im calling a rest api using ResTemplate , im using CompletableFuture to do parallel calls , this is my code :

```
   List<CompletableFuture<Object>> allUsersFuturesCalls = new ArrayList<>();

// User list contains 300 user
    for (User user : listOfUsers) {
      // 1 Mapping Excel to Model
      User userToCreate = userService.MapUser(user);

        // Add create user service to the list
        // userService.createUser calls restTemplate POST
        allUsersFuturesCalls.add(userService.createUser(userToCreate));
     
    }

    // Trigger Calls 
    CompletableFuture.allOf(allUsersFuturesCalls.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).join();
```

this code is work fine when the `listOfUsers` contains `300` elements , it takes 1 min but when i work with another `listOfUsers`  that contains  `4000` users the execution time is increased and it takes more than 15 min to trigger make 4k Calls.

do you have any idea on how to increase the performance of my CompletableFuture calls.

Regards!

Comment: if the service you call is not yours - there is not too much to do, as I suppose most of the work happens there. But to mention one thing - your approach may overwhelm callable service. From my point of view it makes sense to do kind of partitioning. Also keep in mind that RestTemplate uses connection pool of 10 connections by default. So even your 300 requests run not parallel in fact.

Comment: @DanilaZharenkov thanks for your response. The service that Im calling is mine , it's a classic rest controller that expose a post endpoint to save my user object. What's the change that I can made in my controller? Thanks

Comment: `RestTemplate` btw is deprecated, you could try to use `WebClient` for instance

Comment: @Eugene is replacing restemplate by webclient will resolve my problem and reduce the execution time?

Comment: I think this is an ideal scenario for using a parallel stream, instead of completablefuture. That will serve your purpose. well.

Comment: @AnkitSharma do you have any code example to implement parallel stream? Thanks

Comment: no, it will most probably not. It seems only reasonable for those calls to get to 15 min, as your 300 calls are completed in 1 min... You could try to specify more threads to `CompletableFuture` by providing a custom Executor to it.

Comment: You seem to repeat a widespread wrong understanding. Calling `join()` does *not* “trigger calls”. The `join()` call only waits for the completion of the already triggered operations. So the first thing to ask yourself, is, whether you actually have to wait for the completion at this point. Besides that, the 4000 operations will take as long as the 4000 operations take. It’s a fundamental design problem. The right solution would be an API that allows to create a list of users in one call, instead of requiring one request per user. But you’re probably not in a position to change that API…